# How to use module's location inside a function in the module - python

Tags: python, file, module

I have a file that contains all my python functions called *my_funcs.py*. The folder containing this file is added to my pythonpath so that I can import it from wherever I need to use it.

I want to write a function that can use the location of the file but it will be inside the module itself. For example, if I were to import the module in an ipython session, then I could use

```
import my_funcs as mf
location = mf.__file__
print(location)
>>> '/path/to/my/Functions/my_funcs.py'
```

How can I make a variable like that inside one of the functions inside *my_funcs.py* itself? I need this to be able to access something relative to the location of the folder *Functions*, (loaded a saved file from `'/path/to/my/Functions/Data/saved_file.npy'`) but as this is a folder I download on different servers through git, the absolute path location changes and needs to be a variable I can calculate/recall rather than hardcode it. It also needs to be a solution that works on both python2.7 and 3.x

Comment: `__file__` did not work?

Comment: Your question is not clear.Please share directory structure and file names also.

Comment: @python_user __file__ works! I didn't realise I could do this for the current file location, I thought it needed to be appended after some module.

Comment: it doesnt have to,  it is a special name, just like `__name__`

Comment: @infinity_milesman I'm not sure what is not so clear, I have given a direct path the module I want to import, as well as given the path of the files that I want to access - again the path is direct and shows how it goes into the same folder.

Comment: @python_user thank you, if you were to make it an answer, I can upvote it and say it is solved

Comment: I do not know if it is a dupe but I will do so

Comment: @python_user I couldn't find a question asking the same question, but my search was by no means exhaustive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `__file__` in your `my_funcs.py` file. `__file__` is a special name in python (like `__name__`) so it does not need to be accessed using a module.

Comment: Worked perfectly, as in the comments of my question, I hadn't realised this could be done inside the file/module itself. Thanks